# Disk doesn't contain a valid partition table

Tags: amazon-ec2

I was running a m1.small instance ec2 ubuntu instance. I was running out of disk space, so I upgraded my instance to medium. When I upgraded I actually got 429.5 GB of space and after that I added 10 gb of volume too. When I run the "sudo fdisk -l" command I got this results.

```
Disk /dev/sda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sda2: 429.5 GB, 429461078016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 52212 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda2 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdf: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1305 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

sda1 is the primary parition and sda2 is what I got added upgrading my system to medium.

But the problem persists, I am not able to pull the code from git, it is giving me this error.

```
remote: Counting objects: 409, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (236/236), done.
fatal: write error: No space left on device
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal and expected that partitions themselves (sda1 and sda2) do not contain valid partitions tables inside.

If you are using LVM, you could use `vgadd` to add sda2 to your volume group, then use `lvextend` to extend the logical volume, then whatever appropriate tool is relevant for the filesystem you chose (`resize2fs` for ext2/3/4).

Without LVM, you could delete sda2, then increase the size of sda1 with `fdisk`(delete and recreate it, being very careful to use the same start location), then use the relevant filesystem resize tool.

Claiming sdf with LVM is the same process. Without LVM you'll have to mount it at a separate location to make use of it.

Comment: hi @bofh I am using ubuntu ec2 instance, I dont think so I can use any LVM's. I am not sure about this

Comment: I felt its quite complicated.